# Comparing two strings excluding number in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two strings stored in two different tables:

1. `Error code=1 on A team`.
2. `Error code=2 on A team`.

I want to compare these two strings in SQL in such a way that numbers should be ignored i.e. when I compare these strings I should get output of the condition as true. I am using Oracle DB: how can I do this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: done @GordonLinoff

Comment: @ManishKumar - Sharing the logic: *Delete the number after =, and then use compare method*!

Comment: select   regexp_replace('Error code=1 on A team.', '[0-9]', '') from dual ;

Comment: Do you need to exclude ALL numbers from the text, or just what comes after the = sign? If you have two teams, A1B and A3B, do you need to exclude 1 and 3 also, so the team names match?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Regexp_replace(t1.A, '[0-9]') =
          ( SELECT Regexp_replace(t2.A, '[0-9]')  FROM tab2 t2 ) THEN 'Yes'
         ELSE 'No'
       END is_equal
FROM   tab1 t1;
```

I am assuming that the column name from table1 and table2 both are A, You may add another join condition if it is available instead of subquery .